# Error reverse engineering Azure resource to .bicep file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-bicep

I have an Azure ASP.NET Core app and various Azure components (App Service, Function App, SQL DB) that were created manually via the Azure Portal UI. I want to reverse engineer the Azure resources to .bicep files but I get an error in VSC. Ideally I'd use Visual Studio (What I've been using for development) but there doesn't seem to be an option.

I do the following in VSC:

1. Create an empty file `myresource.bicep`
2. Get the Resource Id from the Azure extension by selecting "View properties" for the entity. E.g. "Id" property for App Service.
3. Press `ctrl+shift+p / "Bicep: Insert resource" /` Paste in the Resource Id.

The error is as follows:
Caught exception fetching resource: The ChainedTokenCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.

```
- Azure CLI not installed
- Az.Account module >= 2.2.0 is not installed.
```

I've checked the following:

1. Extensions installed today: Azure Account, Azure App Service, Azure CLI Tools, Azure Contain Apps, Azure Databases, Azure Developer CLI, Azure Functions, Azure Resource.
2. Checked that I've installed all extensions mentioned with various online tutorials.
3. I can view each Azure resource with the Azure extension.

What am I doing wrong? I haven't typed any terminal/console messages. Am I supposed to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reverse engineer Azure resources to `.bicep` files, no terminal/console messages are required. You can create an empty `.bicep` file in `Visual Studio Code` and then use the `Azure extension` to acquire the `Resource Id` of the entity you want to reverse engineer. Following that, you can use the `"Bicep: Insert resource"` command to insert the resource declaration into the `.bicep` file by specifying the `Resource Id` of an existing resource.

And if the module issue occurs frequently, it indicates that a module was not properly installed.

Install Az accounts module in the `VScode` terminal using
`Install-module az.accounts` command and if it is already installed it shows output warning as below.

[image]

*I also got the similar caught exception when I tried in my environment.*

[image]

Though you added Azure CLI extensions in VScode it wont work. So I installed `Azure CLI` [latest release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-cli#install-or-update) in my local windows. After the installation is done, I copied that `cli folder` from `downloads` to the `.VScode` in file explorer.

[image]

I restarted my `Visual Studio Code` once it is added in the corresponding folder. To check whether it is working fine, I gave `az` in `VScode` terminal and it shows all the commands as follows.

[image]

Then authorize it with the Azure account using

`az login --scope https://management.azure.com//.default` command.

[image]

Inserted an existing resource successfully by going into `Bicep: Insert a resource` from command palette.

[image]

Comment: Az.Accounts is already installed.  If I try and run Install-Module then I get this error: PackageManagement\Install-Package : The following commands are already available on this
system:'Login-AzAccount,Logout-AzAccount,Resolve-Error,Send-Feedback'. This module 'Az.Accounts' may override the existing commands. If you still want to
install this module 'Az.Accounts', use -AllowClobber parameter.
ifiedErrorId : CommandAlreadyAvailable,Validate-ModuleCommandAlreadyAvailable,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage...

Comment: Did you install Azure cli file as I mentioned in the above answer. @ChrisFellows